# Determining which range (bucket) a given number belongs to

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have a sequence of ranges (i.e., buckets or pigeon-holes),
starting at 0, all the same size (for example, 32):

> [0…31], [32…63], [64…95], …

Given a non-negative integer, how can I determine
(in a bash or other shell script) which bucket it belongs to?
For example:

1. if a given number=15 then response = [0…31] (i.e., min=0 and max=31)
2. if a given number=35 then response = [32…63] (i.e., 32 && 63)

Comment: This could be clarified a lot. How exactly are the min and max values formed? What's the meaning of the last value of 10 000?

Comment: @ikkachu, MIN starts from zero  and the increment is 32 while the MAX is the highest number in a particular range as shown in my example. 10000 can be used as the limits but it's not important.

Comment: This is actually a math problem.  Once you figure out the equation to use, you can always come back to get help implementing it in a shell script if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
range() {
  # increment
  incr=$1
  # input
  input=$2

  # mathematically, min = floor( input/incr )*incr
  # then max = min+incr-1
  # but `floor' isn't necessary in bash because it uses integer division

  min=$(( input/incr*incr ))
  max=$(( min+incr-1 ))

  echo $min $max
}
```

Then:

```
$ range 32 15
0 31
$ range 32 35
32 63
```